# Dotted line instead of \hline in table environment

Tags: tables, arydshln

I am trying to get a dotted line in the table instead of `\hline`, but I can't get the output.

`arydshln` and `dashrule` packages are available to get the dashed line, but I can't find any packages to get a dotted line in table.

Is any package available for this style?

Comment: take a look at this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10261/26074

Comment: yes i looked that page, they used arydshln package for getting the dashed line (---------------), but i need dotted lines (...........)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The package [arydshln](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/arydshln) by Hiroshi Nakashima provides dashed lines, but they can be changed to look like dots, somehow, by reducing the dash length and increasing the gap a little bit (both default to `4pt`)

Change the lengths `\dashlinedash`, `\dashlinegap` accordingly and `\arrayrulewidth` eventually.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{arydshln}

\setlength{\dashlinedash}{0.2pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{4.5pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
& \\
This is a & nice table \\
& \\
\hdashline
& \\
\end{tabular}


% Another combination of values
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
This is yet & another nice table \\
\hdashline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: In a previous version I had`\usepackage{array}` -- this package is not needed, so I removed it from the code.

Answer (score 29):

Just playing around, I came up with a way to add dashed and [true] dotted horizontal lines to `tabular` entities.  It could be made more robust, in that it assumes one has `\tabcolsep` border on each side of a column (which of course can be overridden by `@{}` macros).  That aside, it automatically works for different font sizes and different values of `\arraystretch`.

it provides `\tabdashline` and `\tabdotline` which are kind of like `\hline`, but it only works on a single column (which means it can be changed from column to column).  Parameters include `\rulewidth`, the thickness of the dash line, `\replength`, a repetition length for each dash/dot on the line, and a macro `\dashfrac{}`, for setting the dash length as fraction of `\replength`.  Note that `\rulewidth` and `\dashfrac{}` have no effect on the `\tabdotline`, since it is using a period as the repeated glyph.  However, the spacing of the dots is controlled by `\replength`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newlength\replength
\newcommand\repfrac{.33}
\newcommand\dashfrac[1]{\renewcommand\repfrac{#1}}
\setlength\replength{1.5pt}
\newcommand\rulewidth{.6pt}
\newcommand\tdashfill[1][\repfrac]{\cleaders\hbox to \replength{%
  \smash{\rule[\arraystretch\ht\strutbox]{\repfrac\replength}{\rulewidth}}}\hfill}
\newcommand\tabdashline{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\tabcolsep]{\tdashfill\hfil}}\tdashfill\hfil%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\tabcolsep]{\tdashfill\hfil}}%
  \\[-\arraystretch\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax]%
}
\newcommand\tdotfill[1][\repfrac]{\cleaders\hbox to \replength{%
  \smash{\raisebox{\arraystretch\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-.1ex\relax}{.}}}\hfill}
\newcommand\tabdotline{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\tabcolsep]{\tdotfill\hfil}}\tdotfill\hfil%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\tabcolsep]{\tdotfill\hfil}}%
  \\[-\arraystretch\dimexpr\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox\relax]%
}
\begin{document}

Compare tabdashline to tabdotline to hline

\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
top\\
\tabdashline
bottom\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 vs.
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
top\\
\tabdotline
bottom\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 vs.
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
top\\
\hline
bottom\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Compare multiple columns:

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
top & column with 0.7 dashfrac\\
\tabdashline & \replength=.4ex\relax\dashfrac{0.7}\tabdashline
bottom & and a replength of .4ex\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

With arraystretch of 1.3:

\def\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
top\\
\tabdashline
bottom\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 vs.
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
top\\
\hline
bottom\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` provides (among other features) a command `\hdottedline` to draw horizontal dotted lines and a specifier `:` in the preamble for the vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|c:c|}
\hline
first & second \\
\hdottedline
third & last \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `arydshln`'s `cdashline`?

Comment: @Federico Schardong: You create a new question on this site for your question and I would give you a detailed answer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648524/nicematrix-cdashline-alternative

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}


\begin{tblr}{|c|[dotted]c|[dotted]c|}
  \hline
    Alpha   & Beta & Gamma   \\
  \hline[dotted]
    Epsilon & Zeta & Eta     \\
  \hline[dotted]
    Iota    & Kapp & Lambdaa \\
  \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]