# how to format a big table

Tags: tables

```
    \documentclass[final,3p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}          
      \usepackage{amssymb}
       \usepackage{multirow}
       \usepackage{amsmath}  
      \usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
   \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{tikz, graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}

\setcitestyle{square,numbers,comma,sort&compress}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure}
\makeatother
%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\journal{AA}
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[!htbp]
   \caption{AAAA}
   \label{XXXXX}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
             ll
            S[table-format=1.4]
       *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                        }
     \toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{A} % "[-1ex]" correction of the vertical 
           position of cell content.
                     % it is required because of the use of lines from 
       "booktabs"
       & \multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{B}
         & {\multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{C}
                    & \multicolumn{5}{c}{D}                 \\
       \cmidrule{4-8}
       &   &        & {dd}     & {ddd}     &   
      {ddd}   & {dddd}  & {Proposed}      \\
      \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{XZA}
        & Vertical & 0.9085 & -0.0090 & -0.0035 & -0.0181 &  0.0061 & 
       -0.0029  \\
        & Horizontal  & 0.9376 & -0.0002 &  0.0011 & -0.0164 &  0.0180 &  
          0.0021  \\
        & Diagonal & 0.8635 & -0.0066 & -0.0029 &  0.0004 & -0.0079 &   
        0.0006  \\
       \end{tabular*}
       \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

I want the border lines in this table, what should be done, can somebody help,
I am getting overbull hbox, how can i fix this?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please complete your code snippet to a minimal document including `\documentclass` so that others can compile this.  Also please see the [`booktabs` package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for good advice about styling of tables.

Comment: What you mean by "border lines". Vertical lines, maybe? Please elaborate.

Comment: your edited code is still not complete. i cant compile it. and please, preserve your original table code, not mix with solutions from answers. with this make received answers irrelevant (what for your original code are not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- i wouldn't draw vertical lines. specially not in combination with rules from the package `booktabs`. it will become ugly (to my taste).
- your table is not consistent. the first row is not complete (in mwe below i change number of columns spanned by `\multicolumn{5}{c}{D}`
- for columns with number i would use column type `S` from package `siunitx`

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\journal{AA}
%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                ll
                S[table-format=1.4]
           *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                            }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{A} % "[-1ex]" correction of the vertical position of cell content.  
                         % it is required because of the use of lines from "booktabs"
    & \multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{B} 
             & {\multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{C}}       
                        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{D}                 \\
    \cmidrule{4-8}
&   &        & {Q}     & {R}     & {s}     & {T}     & {P}      \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{AA}
& H & 0.9376 & -0.0002 &  0.0011 & -0.0164 &  0.0180 &  0.0021  \\
& V & 0.9085 & -0.0090 & -0.0035 & -0.0181 &  0.0061 & -0.0029  \\
& D & 0.8635 & -0.0066 & -0.0029 &  0.0004 & -0.0079 &  0.0006  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
see my splendid table \ref{XXXXX}.

\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

- however, if you like to have cell contents in "prison", than you can do this with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l||S[table-format=1.4]|
                 *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]|}}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{A}   
    & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{B} 
             & {\multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{C}}       
                        & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{D}                 \\
    \cline{4-8}
&   &        & {Q}     & {R}     & {s}     & {T}     & {P}      \\
    \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{AA}
& H & 0.9376 & -0.0002 &  0.0011 & -0.0164 &  0.0180 &  0.0021  \\
    \cline{2-8}
& V & 0.9085 & -0.0090 & -0.0035 & -0.0181 &  0.0061 & -0.0029  \\
    \cline{2-8}
& D & 0.8635 & -0.0066 & -0.0029 &  0.0004 & -0.0079 &  0.0006  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit**
after your editing of question, my above answer (considered your document preamble) gives

[image]

this table looks ugly to me.  would turn it into the next form:

[image]

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\journal{AA}
%\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=1.8cm,left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption{AAAA}
\label{XXXXX}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ll
                S[table-format=1.4]
           *{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                            }
    \toprule
\multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{A}
    & \multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{B}
             & {\multirow{2}{*}[-1ex]{C}}
                        & \multicolumn{5}{c}{D}                 \\
    \cmidrule{4-8}
&   &        & {Q}     & {R}     & {s}     & {T}     & {P}      \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{AA}
& H & 0.9376 & -0.0002 &  0.0011 & -0.0164 &  0.0180 &  0.0021  \\
& V & 0.9085 & -0.0090 & -0.0035 & -0.0181 &  0.0061 & -0.0029  \\
& D & 0.8635 & -0.0066 & -0.0029 &  0.0004 & -0.0079 &  0.0006  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
see my splendid table \ref{XXXXX}.
\end{document}
```

as you can see, in the both cases referencing of table works!

Comment: +1. In the first example, I'd be tempted to replace `*{6}{S[table-format=-1.4]` with `S[table-format=1.4]*{5}{S[table-format=-1.4]` for ever-so-slightly tighter spacing.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much to pointed me on this ... in the second table i use such a column setting, apparently i forgot to correct this in the first table :-(. corrected now!

Comment: i can't refer this table in my text, how can i refer it? is it because of table*

Comment: @Upstart, for referencing you need to add `\caption{...}` and `label{...}` to table, which should be in `table` float environment. bot are not given in your mwe, so i didn't consider this in my answer.

Comment: yes i have done this, but it is showing an overfull\hbox. How do i resize the table, to make it fit the page

Comment: @Upstart, first you need to provide mwe, a complete small document which we can compile and see what is your problem. please edit your question. otherwise, we can only guess, but we can't really help you.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: i have edited the question and it should compile now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you want:

```
\begin{tabular}{|llrrrrrr|}
```

The change will create a left and right border outline.

See also this question for more info on table formatting:
[Table Border Options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/table-border-options)

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's generally preferred to include full examples with screen shots, if appropriate. Zarko's answer follows this model, for example