# Vertical rule with NiceTabular

Tags: nicematrix

I’m trying to draw a vertical line with thickness 1pt with `nicematrix` package, but I obtain error compilation... any help is welcome. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\NiceMatrixOptions{custom-line ={letter =I,width = 1 pt}}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cIcc}
   $A$      & $1$   &    $2$        \\ \hline
   $B$      & $3$   &    $3$     
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Thanks.
C.W

Comment: Hi, @Charly Watson, and welcome to TeX.SE. Are you receiving this error message: `Package nicematrix Error: The key 'custom-line' is unknown for the command(nicematrix) \NiceMatrixOptions. }`?

Comment: Hi @FHZ. Not exactly, my error message is the following:

 ‘NiceMatrix/RulesBis/width’ is unknown and is being ignored

Answer (score 5):

The compilation error can be avoided using `tikz` to set the line in the `custom-line I` and the key `line width`.

The key `total-width` is then used to reserve the space for the new column/rule.

[image: b]

(with nicematrix.sty    2022/03/11 v6.8)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    
\NiceMatrixOptions
{
    custom-line =
    {letter = I ,
    tikz = {line width=5pt, red },
    total-width=5pt 
    },  % changed <<<<<<
}
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{cIcc}
            $A$      & $1$   &    $2$        \\ \hline
            $B$      & $3$   &    $3$     
        \end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

From the commented code

> The *key total-width must be used only when the key tikz is used*. When used,
> the key total-width specifies the width of the rule: it will be used to
> reserve space (in the preamble of the array or in the command for the
> horizontal rules).

Comment: +1 for letting explicit the need of version. I was working with version 5.13. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I reproduce below some examples from [CTAN -- nicematrix](https://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) with a few alterations.

The command `custom-line` appears at

- 5.6 Commands for customized rules

where the given example starts with: `\begin{NiceTabular}{lcIcIc}[custom-line = {letter=I, color=blue}]` and in the sequence there is another example with `TikZ` and `\NiceMatrixOptions`. Unfortunately, both examples gave me the following error message: `Package nicematrix Error: The key 'custom-line' is unknown for the(nicematrix) environment {NiceTabular}. ...cIc}[custom-line = {letter=I, color=blue}]`.

However, there is a way around. Sections:

- 5 The rules

  - 5.2 The thickness and the color of the rules
  - 5.3.2 The keys hvlines and hvlines-except-borders

present commands `rules/color` and `rules/width`, that might be useful, but are not exactly a new `custom-line` you may define for the whole document and use it where you want.

A MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c}[rules/color=blue,rules/width=3pt]
  \hline
   rose  & tulipe &   lys    \\
   arum  &  iris  & violette \\
  muguet & dahlia &  souci   \\
  \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccc}[hvlines,rules/color=green!50!black,rules/width=4pt]
  rose & tulipe & marguerite & dahlia \\
  violette & \Block[draw=red]{2-2}{\LARGE fleurs} & & souci \\
  pervenche & & & lys \\
  arum & iris & jacinthe & muguet
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I still may check how to define the new column line type globally, although I'm not an expert in this package. This answer is more a quick fix than a definite approach to the problem, or even an explanation why your problem appears.

Comment: Many thanks @FHZ. But I want only one vertical rule with different thickness... your solution give all rules (both vertical and horinzontal) with the same thickness (3pt and 4pt)

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure, but you will probably have to use another solution or package. Check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/tabular-border-style) for example.

Comment: And maybe you could edit your question presenting your need for defining multiples rule styles and using them along the document.

Answer (score 3):

A small variation of the nice {Simon Dispa answer (+1):

```
\documentclass[border=3.14152, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\NiceMatrixOptions
{custom-line = {letter = I,
                tikz = {},   % <---
                width = 2mm} % <---
}


\begin{document}
\[
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cIcc}
   A      & 1   &    2        \\ \hline
   B      & 3   &    3
\end{NiceTabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some edit in your code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
%   \NiceMatrixOptions{custom-line ={letter =I,width = 1 pt}}
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{c|cc} %<-- changed
            $A$      & $1$   &    $2$        \\ \hline
            $B$      & $3$   &    $3$     
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to answer OP's question. Package nicematrix presents a `custom-line` command with `I` as column separator. In your answer, you just removed letter `I` for the conventional column separator `|`.